# Warning: Prop `id` did not match in tradingview widget

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api

I am trying to use TradingViewWidget in react to show charts but the chart is showing sometimes and sometimes not. Getting this Warning in console

**Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "tradingview-widget-0.7679528527764021" Client: "tradingview-widget-0.3972755056284276"**

and this is my code -

```
import TradingViewWidget from 'react-tradingview-widget';
import { Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const TechnicalChart = () => {
  return (
      <Segment basic >
        <TradingViewWidget symbol="OANDA:USDTHB"/>
      </Segment>
  );
};
export default TechnicalChart;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are using some sort of server side rendering, I was getting this error in Nextjs, and that was because of SSR, and I did sth like this:

```
const TvChart = dynamic(() => import("TvChart"), { ssr: false });
```

and then used it as:

```
<TvChart/>
```

and this is the chart component:

```
import TradingViewWidget from "react-tradingview-widget";
const TvChart = () => {
   return <TradingViewWidget symbol="NASDAQ:AAPL" />;
};
export default TvChart;
```

and now it works well.